# What is this flower with purple and white petals that roll up to form a tube?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]

I found this very cool looking flower but have not been able to identify it.  If you know what it is called please post your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: what part of the  world did you see this flower in?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your contribution!     :-)

Answer (score 12):

I think that's an [osteospermum whirligig](http://www.oakleafgardening.com/plants/osteospermum-whirlygig/), also commonly known as African Daisy or African Cape Daisy.

It's a perennial in USDA Zones 10 or 11, and sub-tropical regions, and is a long-blooming annual in cooler climates. It's shrub-like in shape, low-growing, and measures 8" to 12" high and 12" wide at maturity. Very versatile, it's a great garden bed or border plant, will trail over a rock wall, and also grows well in containers. It prefers sun and well-drained soil, but is very adaptable, making it easy to grow, even for beginners. Each of those unusual flowers lasts a long time, but dead-heading them encourages faster, more profuse growth.

Further information can be found [here](http://depts.washington.edu/uwbg/news/2013/08/30/september-2013-plant-profile-osteospermum-whirligig/), and [here](http://www.mooresvalleynurseries.co.nz/catalogue/Perennials/d0696851-b6e2-4551-b2dd-63263c763dfa/catalogue.aspx).

Comment: This one is widely available  for sale in the uk as a summer bedding plant, in a variety of colours.